# Get a draggable/choose cursor for matplotlib RangeSlider

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, rangeslider

So i'm trying to build an interactive UI to handle image analysis and i need to define two boundaries.
The most logical solution would be to use matplotlib's [RangeSlider](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/widgets_api.html?highlight=rangeslider#matplotlib.widgets.RangeSlider). However I have found it to be inpractical because you cannot decide which range you will move when clicking. Sadly they did not implement something such as (for ex.) right click to change the highest range. I can also not get a draggable cursor, though in the exemples of matplotlib [it seemed to be possibe](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/widgets/range_slider.html):

[image: Rangeslider of matplotlib demo]

Here you can see white circles at each end of the slider boundaries, allowing one to specify which boundary one wants to move.
However when i try this code this is what i get :

[image: Own rangeslider obtained]

No draggable cursor is present anymore. Is there any way to get a draggable cursor back, and to decide which bound will be moving each time ? (setting draggable true doesn't achieve this).
I'm using matplotlib '3.4.3', with Anaconda and backend 'Qt5Agg'
Many thanks

Comment: What is the problem that distinguishes your output from that of the matplotlib docs? I fail to understand what you want to change.

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear enough adn thanks for pointing this out. Matplotlib demo had cursors on the slider that one can drag (little white circles), while the recent version does not have these cursors anymore, only a blue filling. So if i click inside the blue area, i cannot chose if this moves the right or left boundary.
I edited my post to make this clearer.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. The widget surface is slightly different for 3.4 compared to 3.5 (as we can see in your pictures) but the functionality is the same. You click on the left or right border of the slider and drag it where intended. I just tested it with 3.4.3 on Windows/Python 3.8. No obscure behavior.

Comment: Well it's true you can partly drag the bound, however you have some strange behaviour. For example if you try to drag the right bound to the extreme left at some point your cursor will pass over the left bound and move both at once. This is why i would need a way to move a specific bound at any moment. Maybe i need something more like detecting right click to move right bound, or left click for left bound..

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem (Win 10/Python 3.8/matplotlib 3.4.3 or 3.5.1 using [the slider example from their gallery](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/widgets/range_slider.html)). I suggest filing a [bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) with full system specifications and a description of the problem, possibly with a link to a gif showing the unintended behavior.

Comment: I just tested also on Ubuntu - likewise no unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I noticed on the matplotlib demo example that in fact, when dragging one bound (for exemple the left one, passing over the right one), matplotlib will automatically change your selection to the other bound. This is the behaviour i would like to avoid.
For exemple if my bounds are 10 and 30, i cannot move the left 10 bound up to 50 to get 30,50. it will select the other bound before i get past it. This usually result in something like 24 50. (matplotlib lets go of the bound a bit early)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i did not find how to make the draggable white circle appear. However if found a way to be able to decide which bound will be moving (by default in matplotlib it is the bound closer to your click). This just adds behaviours for other mouse clicks.

So one creates the RangeSlider

> ```
> # Make a horizontal slider to control the bounds.
> axbounds = plt.axes([0.25, 0.145, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='lightgoldenrodyellow')
> my_sliderbounds = RangeSlider(
>     ax=axbounds,
>     label='Bounds', dragging=True, 
>     valmin=0, valmax=100, valinit=(0,100), valstep=1 )
> my_sliderbounds.on_changed(update) #calls the update function when value changes
> ```

Then you connect your canvas to a click detection (or any button really)

```
cid = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick_img)
```

When the button is clicked, it calls the onclick_img function. We check that we are on the slider axe and what was clicked. left click is already handled by matplotlib. I will use right click to set the right boundary position, middle click to set the left boundary position.

```
def onclick_img(event): #we detect clicks on the canvas.
    if event.inaxes==axbounds:    
            
        if event.button == 1: #MouseButton.LEFT, already 
            pass
        if event.button == 2: #MouseButton.MIDDLE : left bound
            clicked_x = int(event.xdata)                
            my_sliderbounds.set_val( ( clicked_x , max ( my_sliderbounds.val) ) ) 
        if event.button == 3: #MouseButton.RIGHT : right 
            clicked_x = int(event.xdata)
            my_sliderbounds.set_val( [ min( my_sliderbounds.val) , clicked_x ] )
```

As Mr.T pointed out the draggable behaviour seems to be same, even without the white circle appearance. But i got some strange behaviour when one bound would be dragged over the other. This i don't know how to solve.